# Why are planet's maximal/minimal angular speed ratio harmonic?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion, planets, celestial-mechanics, harmonics

See this Wikipedia page for [Harmonices Mundi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonices_Mundi#Content), a book by Kepler (yes, he was the one to discover the three Kepler's laws). The author writes:

> He found that the difference between the maximum and minimum angular speeds of a planet in its orbit approximates a harmonic proportion. For instance, the maximum angular speed of the Earth as measured from the Sun varies by a semitone (a ratio of 16:15), from mi to fa, between aphelion and perihelion. Venus only varies by a tiny 25:24 interval (called a diesis in musical terms).

Can anyone explain why this is the case physically (**possibly with mathematical formulae**)? Or is it just a coincidence?

Answer (score 2):

It’s a coincidence.

He also thought the spacing of the planets was related to nested Platonic solids. It isn’t.

His three laws, not his numerology, are why he’s rightly famous.

Comment: Disappointing, but expected.

Comment: As with most attempts at numerology, the coincidence usually goes away when you get more accurate measurements.